# Linux command to filter date string from file and compare it against a date

Tags: linux, command-line, date

I have a file that looks like:

```
ASDF,100090,D84,2007-12-29T01:07:35Z
ASDF,101090,F84,2008-01-03T01:09:36Z
ASDF,101190,h84,2008-01-04T01:07:31Z
ASDF,178915,r54,2008-01-15T01:09:21Z
ASDF,144290,k74,2008-02-05T01:03:31Z
```

I want to find the count of lines older than date `2008-01-10`.
I am able to list the dates with the command `cut -d "," -f 4 2008A.csv | cut -d "T" -f 1`:

```
2007-12-29
2008-01-03
2008-01-04
2008-01-15
2008-02-05
```

But how do I find the number of lines older than `2008-01-10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure:

1. inject a marker with a semi-date that is numerically slightly lower than your boundary date;
2. apply numeric sort;
3. stop processing at the marker, without passing the marker line itself;
4. count lines.

The code (it starts with your code):

```
{ cut -d "," -f 4 2008A.csv | cut -d "T" -f 1; \
printf "2008-01-09.9 marker\n"; } |
sort -n |
sed '/marker/Q' |
wc -l
```

Notes:

- `Q` in `sed` is not POSIX, your `sed` may not understand it. If so, use `sed '/marker/q'`; but this will pass the marker line, you need to filter it out before `wc -l` xor decrease the final result by one.
- Beware of empty lines (if any); `sort` will place them at the very beginning, this will alter the result. My answer assumes there are none. A newline just before EOF (end of file) is OK, [it doesn't create an empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `grep`:

```
grep -v '2008-01-\(0[0-9]\|10\)' 2008A.csv
```

or

```
grep -v -E '2008-01-(0[0-9]|10)' 2008A.csv
```

(in other words, remove all the lines with `2008-01-0something` or `2008-01-10`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  File contains dates of different months and years.  Is it possible to  convert the string values to date and then filter them after comparing with a date, say `2008-01-10`?

Comment: If you want a random date, then Kamil's answer is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dategrep` from [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/):

```
$ dategrep '<2008-01-10' <<EOF
ASDF,100090,D84,2007-12-29T01:07:35Z
ASDF,101090,F84,2008-01-03T01:09:36Z
ASDF,101190,h84,2008-01-04T01:07:31Z
ASDF,178915,r54,2008-01-15T01:09:21Z
ASDF,144290,k74,2008-02-05T01:03:31Z
EOF
=>
  ASDF,100090,D84,2007-12-29T01:07:35Z
  ASDF,101090,F84,2008-01-03T01:09:36Z
  ASDF,101190,h84,2008-01-04T01:07:31Z
```